# While clicking submit i get an error but its still inserting data in the database

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, post

I made a form and when i don't fill in the form i get an error just how i wanted.
Example of the error i made:

[Error if you dont fill in anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90RDN.png)

[error if you fill in capital letters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QngHt.png)

so now if you press enter you need to get a error. Its giving me the error but then its inserting empty data which is wrong, it should not insert data at all.

THIS IS MY CODE:

```
<?php


// Connecting to database
require('config.php');


if (isset($_POST['companyname']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['surname']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['function']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {






    // Values to insert
    $companyname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['companyname']);
    $name        = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);
    $surname     = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['surname']);
    $email       = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
    $function    = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['function']);
    $password    = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);


    $companyname_error = "";

    function test_input($data)
    {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }


    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {


        // empty
        if (empty($_POST['companyname'])) {

            $companyname_error = "companyname is required!";

        } else {
            $companyname = test_input($_POST["companyname"]);
            //check characters validation
            if (!preg_match("/^[^A-Z]+$/", $companyname)) {

                $companyname_error = "Only use small letters and white spaces!";

            }
        }
    }



    // voer insert uit
    $sql = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO company (companyname) VALUES (?)");
    $sql->bind_param('s', $companyname);

    $sql->execute();


    //RESULT
    $result = $sql->get_result();

    // id
    $companyId = mysqli_insert_id($con);


    //insert INTO
    $sql = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO employee (name, surname, email, function, password, companyid) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $sql->bind_param('ssssss', $name, $surname, $email, $function, $password, $companyId);
    $sql->execute();
    $result = $sql->get_result();




}


?>
```

HTML form:

```
<form class="form_register_page" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="register_headers">full name</label> <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter your full name" type="text">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="register_headers">Full last name</label> <input class="form-control" id="lastname" name="surname" placeholder="Enter your last name" type="text">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="register_headers">company name</label> <input class="form-control" id="company" name="companyname" placeholder="Enter your company" type="text">
                            <span class="error">* <?php echo $companyname_error;?></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="register_headers">function</label> <input class="form-control" id="function" name="function" placeholder="Enter your function" type="text">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="register_headers">E-Mail adress</label> <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your E-Mail adress" type="text">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="register_headers">Password</label> <input class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password" type="password">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="form-check">
                                <label class="form-check-label"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"> I agree all statements in <b>terms of service</b></label>
                            </div>
                        </div><button class="click_more" type="submit">Register</button> 







                    <span class="error">

                    <?php 

                        echo $companyname_error;


                    ?>
                    </span>



                        </form>
```

Comment: `test_input()` don't use that.

Comment: i made a clear image of the code refresh it

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string()` don't use those neither; you're already using a prepared statement and probably doing more harm than good.

Comment: Can you post your html form?

Comment: yes i will im still trying to figure this stackoverflow out ;(

Comment: @YoungKesinova I added your form in an edit now.

Comment: You have no condition for your query.  You are running errors and the sql that is why you have this situation instead of either errors or sql.  Place your query in an else statement like this if !errors do sql.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to injection use $hashedWord = password_hash($input['pass'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array("cost" => 17));
for password hashing.

Comment: @Jonny Sorry, didn't see your comment while I was typing up an answer.

Comment: no problem i didnt post it as an answer so leave it

Answer (score 2):

Your $sql->execute() statements are always run because they are completely outside the code blocks which tests for the error conditions and there is no separate test for the errors having being raised. If you put the inserts inside a test for $companyname_error being empty you won't get the inserts. eg

```
if (empty($comanyname_error))
   { 
      do your inserts here 
   }
```